# Expired and "cut" Australian passport with valid Indian (OCI) visa

Tags: visas, passports, india, australian-citizens

Australia's passport renewal process includes the passport official cutting out the machine readable zone of the old passport (middle pages are not touched), if the old passport has not expired. Now for my son, this old "cut" passport has a lifelong Indian visa.

Has anyone travelled to India with visa on the "cut Australian" passport ? Do the airlines or Indian immigration have any requirement of a non-damaged passport. Will they consider this passport as cancelled or damaged? Is damaged like this worse than having a cancelled stamp on the passport ?

Please tell me if it is possible to travel with visa on cut Australian passport.

Comment: @HankyPanky He's not claiming the passport owner does it.  It's standard procedure for Australian passports for at least 20 years for this to happen when you renew an un-expired passport.

Comment: How old is your son?  Specifically for OCI, the rules depend on the age of the person.

Answer (score 7):

When you mention 'visa' I'm presuming you are referring to the "U" Visa in his passport corresponding to his OCI status.

Since 2015, India has ceased issuing these visas, and they are no longer required when entering the country - you only need to present your OCI card.

You will find this information stated on many official websites, such as the [Bureau of Immigration](https://boi.gov.in/content/overseas-citizen-india-oci-cardholder) website (towards the bottom as Note 1) :

> Government of India has decided to dispense with the "U" Visa sticker
>   on the foreign passport of OCI card holders with immediate effect.
>   Accordingly, Immigration authorities shall not insist on production of
>   foreign passport containing the "U" Visa sticker in the case of OCI
>   card holders while they enter/exit India. OCI card holders shall now
>   be given Immigration clearance on the strength of their valid forign
>   passport and OCI Registration Certificate (OCI booklet, popularly
>   known as OCI card).

In addition to this change, India does generally accept visas that are contained in prior passports, and the 'damage' done by removing the machine-readable strip on the bio page does not invalidate that.

HOWEVER if your Son is below 21 years of age, then he is required to obtain a new OCI card whenever he obtains a new passport.  This is not related to the visa, but to the OCI card itself.  The same is also true when passing 50 years of age.

Further information on this can be found on the [CKGS website](https://www.in.ckgs.us/faq/oci/general-oci-questions/881/my-son-is-going-to-be-21-can-he-travel#881)  (CKGS is the company responsible for Indian visas/OCI/etc in the US, so it a legitimate company/website)